# Why doesn't hover psuedo element stay enabled when viewing a child element?

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulty keeping the "hover" state when a child element of said element is being shown.

https://gyazo.com/3787a8082eefb3d619f0318775b1e6dc

Why is this occurring?

I suppose one could use a "hack" to get the parent but that's not a good idea for production.

Perhaps using a button with a selected state could also work better?

HTML:

```
<ul class="main">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Customers</a>
                        <div class="fix">
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Subscriptions</a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Billing</a>
                </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.main > li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.625em;
}

ul.main > li > a:hover, ul.main > li.active > a {
    background: #43B0F1;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

ul.main > li ul.sub {
    display: none;
}

ul.main > li:hover ul.sub {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 4px solid #43B0F1;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.fix { position: relative; margin-top: 1px; display: block; top: -2px;}

ul.sub li {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}
ul.sub li a { display: block; }
ul.sub li:last-child { border: 0; }

ul.sub li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: You should rather give your `li` elements a background-color than the `a` elements. Then it will stay the same color when hovering: ul.main li:hover { background:#43B0F1;}

Comment: @Chris oh my! Rookie mistake, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Did that fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should rather give your `li` elements a background-color than the `a` elements. Then it will stay the same color when hovering:

`ul.main li:hover { background:#43B0F1;}`